# How do I stop the VB compiler from running in C# ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am working on an ASP.NET Web Forms site that is written completely in C#. All initial page loads in one subdirectory cause the VB compiler to run. Oddly, page loads in that directory's subdirectories do not cause the VB compiler to run.

- There are no  elements in the Web.config.
- This happens in every solution that includes the project.
- None of the Microsoft.VisualBasic assemblies are referenced in the project

Is there a setting somewhere that I can change that will disable VB compiler?
 Could this be due to a referenced assembly used in this folder but nowhere else?

Since there seems to be some concern with the validity of this question, I and another senior developer have spent about 10 hours trying to run down this problem. We have searched the code base, visual studio, and online for an answer but it appears to be unique enough that no one has brought it up.

Additionally, when the same code is put in a different directory, the VB compiler does not run on initial page load. This is what leads me to believe there is a setting somewhere that I am missing.

Comment: What makes you believe the VB compiler is running?

Comment: The memory usages spikes to about 95% for 30-60 seconds and a "vbc.exe" process runs. I can stop that process and it doesn't impact the page load, neither does it try to run again on subsequent loads of that same page. However, it will run again on the first load of the other pages in that directory.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I'm not sure there is a minimal, complete, and verifiable example since when I move the code to another folder, it works as expected without running the VB compiler. That's the reason I asked if there is a setting somewhere that someone might know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time I've seen this, it's because of a "badly"-compiled file that exists in the folder structure (not even necessarily the `csproj`).

Check the folder structure of the pages in question, see if there's a bad file located somewhere in there. You may have to `Show All Files` in Visual Studio.

Delete it with extreme prejudice.

Comment: That got it. Thanks!